# micro service practice & recommendations

Tags: web-services, service, architecture, microservices

Is it good idea to separate out implementation of each http verb in different micro service?

For example
GET books/{id} - micro service A
POST books/{id} - micro service B

This appears to be overkill for "books" api but in a typical enterprise an api resource/verb do a lot more than a hello work api.

Comment: Please read basic of microservice , your microservice is separate  based on bounded context not on verb.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it good idea to separate out implementation of each http verb in
>   different micro service?

The boundaries of microservices are usually drawn by separable business concerns. The main reason to do that is for enabling separate teams to be responsible for the complete lifecycle of a service, with minimal external dependencies. This allows for a faster release cycle of services in a complex system.

For understanding the microservices architectural style I recommend reading the [material from Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html).

Comment: Conceptually you are correct. However, you may want to separate out commands and queries in different micro-services. In typical implementation, commands integrate with some relational database and queries with caching solution. So following CQRS principle , even though both GET and POST address  one business concern, I think they should reside in different microservice and also should have different aggregate roots even though they both talk about same bounded context.

Comment: The way I see, different verbs associated with any API has different complexity and might even have different underlying database( especially case of GET), there is no good reason to club everything under one microservice

Comment: The easiest way to answer is - Ask yourself: Do you want to have different teams responsible for different verbs of the http service? If yes you should go with separate services, otherwise it may be added complexity.

Comment: So rationale is just the team? If we keep aside organizational structure does it make sense to segregate on verbs as well?